# Google Play Service:How to get the count of scores in a Leaderboard

Tags: count, google-play, leaderboard

I want to get the count of all scores in a leaderboard, but `loadPlayerCenteredScores` method can not do this, the parameter `maxResults` must between 1 and 25, how can I get count?